# issues after updating to Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, ios8

Could not register the assembly
Error messages that I am getting:

```
'MonoTouch.Dialog-1': MonoTouch.MonoTouchException: Cannot register two managed types('MonoTouch.Dialog.BaseBooleanImageElement+TextWithImageCellView, MonoTouch.Dialog-1, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'
```

and

```
'MonoTouch.Dialog.BaseBooleanImageElement+TextWithImageCellView, xxxxx1, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') with the same native name('MonoTouch_Dialog_BaseBooleanImageElement_TextWithImageCellView').
```

tried with `mtouch` arguments `--registrar:legacy`, not able fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've included both MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll and MonoTouch.Dialog.dll in your app. Choose one.

Comment: `MonoTouch.Dialog.BaseBooleanImageElement+TextWithImageCellView, xxxxx1,` <- there's something else using the same name (copy/pasted code?) and they can't both be registered with the ObjC runtime.

Comment: @user3782957: exactly which assemblies do you reference?